# SELECT using GROUP BY and HAVING not returning records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to select all records that have a duplicate value in the LASTNAME column. This is my code so far

```
If EXISTS( SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'USER_DUPLICATES' AND type = 'U' ) 
    DROP TABLE USER_DUPLICATES
GO

CREATE TABLE USER_DUPLICATES
(
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(MAX),
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(MAX),
    PHONE VARCHAR(MAX),
    EMAIL VARCHAR(MAX),
    TITLE VARCHAR(MAX),
    LMU VARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

INSERT INTO USER_DUPLICATES
(
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME,
    PHONE,
    EMAIL,
    TITLE,
    LMU
)
SELECT
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME,
    PHONE,
    EMAIL,
    TITLE,
    LMU
FROM TM_USER
GROUP BY
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME,
    PHONE,
    EMAIL,
    TITLE,
    LMU
HAVING COUNT(LASTNAME) > 1
```

It does not return any records. I changed the

```
HAVING COUNT(LASTNAME) > 1
```

to

```
HAVING COUNT(LASTNAME) > 0
```

and it returns all the records. I am also certain there are records with the same LASTNAME value. It is written using T-SQL on SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.FIRSTNAME,
    a.LASTNAME,
    a.PHONE,
    a.EMAIL,
    a.TITLE,
    a.LMU
FROM TM_USER a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT LASTNAME
    FROM TM_USER
    GROUP BY LASTNAME
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) b ON a.LASTNAME = b.LASTNAME
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I did this before, but didn't think to rename the TM_USER. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your Group By clause will Group By all the comuns in the list.  Those columns probably define a discreet record of count = 1

You will need to do something like:

```
Select LAST_NAME from TM_USER  GROUP BY LAST_NAME HAVING COUNT(LAST_NAME) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

COUNT function is computed over all grouping expression, not over LASTNAME.

To get unique last names use

```
SELECT LASTNAME FROM TM_USER GROUP BY LASTNAME HAVING COUNT(LASTNAME) > 1
```

If you group by few columns, you will get count of their unique combination even if computing COUNT over single column value.